# multiline.conf how to ignore case on word

Tags: multitail, multitail.conf

using multitail:
https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

I'd like to ignore case on word, let's say to allow for Error ERROR error or even errOrr I tried in multitail.conf the following:

```
cs_re:yellow,,bold:\?i(error)
cs_re:yellow,,bold:(error)/i 
cs_re:yellow,,bold:(\?i)error
```

and many other combinations without luck and I want to try and avoid
typing every combination manually

Thanks again
Sean